# Authorizazion Skipped by you

Tags: centos, robo3t

I need to configure robomongo in Centos so this I obtain this error:

[image]

in the next tab "Authetication" is not set.

I set in `/etc/mongod.conf`

'#net.bindIp: 127.0.0.1'

I add in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --ports 27017 -m comment --comment "100 tcp/27017" -j ACCEPT
```

But I obtain this error? Anyone can help me?

Comment: I *think* it means that you've skipped the authentication step in the RoboMongo GUI - nothing to do with the `mongodb` service. The application is *only* connecting to the server, and not authenticating against it (since the tab isn't filled). It's not an error *per se*, just a notice that you're not testing the authentication details.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ You're right; if you post this as a answer I'll upvote it for you.

Comment: Awesome :) Have done so @VinceBowdren

Answer (score 1):

It means that you've skipped the authentication step in the RoboMongo GUI - nothing to do with the `mongodb` service.

The application is only connecting to the server, and not authenticating against it (since the tab isn't filled). It's not an error per se, just a notice that you're not testing the authentication details.